# Is it possible to generate seamless "mosaic" tiles algorithmically?

Tags: gimp, tiles

I am pretty much a noob with respect to most power features of Gimp and graphics design in general.  I found the tutorial [here](http://www.evoartia.com/Welcome/index.php?page=gimp-cobblestone-tutorial) on texture creation to be very interesting and helpful.  I had a couple of questions regarding it which I can't ask the author as there [apparently] is no comment mechanism.

(1) The basic pattern used by the tutorial looks like it may have been generated by the Distorts|Mosaic filter.  Inspection of the 512x512 pattern reveals that it's actually a tiled 256x256 pattern.  Is it possible to generate a "seamless mosaic" tile algorithmically?

(2) In the event that (1) must be undertaken manually, are there preferred methods for doing so?  I am familiar with the offset x/2,y/2 method and played around with it while looking at this tutorial.  Are there alternative/preferred approaches?

Answer (score 3):

To do so go to Filters > Map > Tile
[image]

Then change size to your desired size
[image]

To change current image uncheck "Create New Image" I would suggest keeping that checked to create a new image. Then click OK.

[image]

As you can see it has created a new image. In my example the original size was 100x100 The tiled size is 400x400.